# authorize.net laravel empty response

Tags: php, laravel-5, authorize.net

I am trying to integrate authorize.net into my laravel shopping cart using the PHP SDK. I am only in the sandbox environment currently. I have it processing the transaction (I can see it in the admin and get the email) but the returned response is all null values.

Code is still a little dirty

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function authnet_chargeCard()
    {

        $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
        $merchantAuthentication->setName(env('AUTHNET_ID'));
        $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(env('AUTHNET_KEY'));

        $refId = 'ref' . time();
        define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");
        // Create the payment data for a credit card
        $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
        $creditCard->setCardNumber("4111111111111111");
        $creditCard->setExpirationDate("1226");
        $creditCard->setCardCode("123");
        $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
        $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

        $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
        $order->setInvoiceNumber("COW-100");
        $order->setDescription("New Item");

        //create a transaction
        $amount=100;
        $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
        $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType( "authCaptureTransaction");
        $transactionRequestType->setAmount($amount);
        $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order);
        $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);

        $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
        $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
        $request->setRefId( $refId);
        $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);

        $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
        $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
        //dd($response);

        if ($response != null)
        {
            $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();

            if (($tresponse != null) && ($tresponse->getResponseCode()== \SampleCode\Constants::RESPONSE_OK) )
            {
                echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
                echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                echo  "Charge Credit Card ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            echo  "Charge Credit card Null response returned";
        }


    }
}
```

Every time my response looks like:

```
CreateTransactionResponse {#352 ▼
  -transactionResponse: null
  -profileResponse: null
  -refId: null
  -messages: null
  -sessionToken: null
}
```

I have even tried temporarily setting the $VERIFY_PEER to false

Comment: also ... i am running it on the laravel homestead vagrant build if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where I went wrong... cleaned up the composer file ... updated it and boom good to go. Sorry to waste virtual space and time with this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function chargeCreditCard(Request $request)
    {
        // Common setup for API credentials
        $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();

        $merchantAuthentication->setName(env('AUTHNET_ID'));
        $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(env('AUTHNET_KEY'));
        $refId = 'ref'.time();

// Create the payment data for a credit card
          $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
          $creditCard->setCardNumber("4242424242424242");
          $creditCard->setExpirationDate( "2038-12");
          //$expiry = $request->card_expiry_year . '-' . $request->card_expiry_month;
          //$creditCard->setExpirationDate($expiry);
          $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
          $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

// Create a transaction
          $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
          $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
          $transactionRequestType->setAmount($request->camount);
          $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
          $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
          $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
          $request->setRefId( $refId);
          $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
          $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
          $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
          if ($response != null)
            {
              $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
              if ($tresponse != null)
              { 
                if($tresponse->getResponseCode() == 1 || $tresponse->getResponseCode() == 4 ){
                   if($tresponse->getResponseCode() == 4){
                     $authCode = "pending";
                   }else{
                     $authCode = $tresponse->getAuthCode();
                   }
                   $transId = $tresponse->getTransId();
                   $result = ['authCode' => $authCode, 'transId' => $transId];
                   $res = $this->transData($result);
                   if($res){
                     Session::flash('success', "The order is successfully placed!"); 
                     return redirect('/');
                   }
                }else{
                   $response = $response->getTransactionResponse()->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText();
                   Session::flash('error', $response); 
                   return redirect('/');
                }
              }
              else
              {
                echo  "Charge Credit Card Null response returned";
              }
            }
            else
            {
              echo  "Charge Credit Card Null response returned";
            }

      return redirect('/');
  }
```

Try above code, its working for me.

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Ok I will go through this